# Given a character with Unicode General Category Ps or Pi, what's the matching closing character?

Tags: python, unicode

Some opening punctuation characters (Unicode General Category `Ps`) and opening quote characters (Unicode General Category `Pi`) happen to have their appropriate closing character at the very next codepoint. For example, `(` is U+0028 and `)` is U+0029. Similarly, `⟪` is U+27EA and `⟫` is U+27EB. But there are exceptions, such as `«` (U+00AB), which has its matching character, `»`, sixteen code points away at at U+00BB.

Given an opening character, how can I determine the appropriate closing character?

(I've tagged this question `python` because I ultimately want to accomplish this in Python, but a language-neutral answer is fine, too.)

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing me to [List of all unicode's open/close brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535172/list-of-all-unicodes-open-close-brackets). In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33357311/1451346) shows the pairs of brackets (i.e., `Ps` and `Pe` characters). But the question of finding a matching quote character (i.e., `Pi` and `Pf` characters) that doesn't happen to be a mirror image, like `’` for `‘`, seems to be left open.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535172/list-of-all-unicodes-open-close-brackets/13535350 ? I started writing an answer, but realized it would mostly be saying the same things as the answers there.

Comment: @hobbs - ditto :D Thanks for finding it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all unicode's open/close brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535172/list-of-all-unicodes-open-close-brackets)

Comment: @hobbs Please see my edit.

Comment: The problem with `Pi` etc. is that their use is ambiguous. For example, in English you usually use double quotes “like this”, whereas in German it's quite common to use them „like this“, so the `Pi` can sometimes opening, sometimes closing here.

Comment: @lenz We can still say that whenever `“` is an opening character, then `”` is the corresponding closing character, can't we? That's all I need here.

Comment: Sure. Depending on the approach, you could even add both pairs and mark them as alternatives. Combine it with a heuristic that picks the one with fewer "left-overs".

Comment: Related: [quotation marks: Analysis and explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496756/3439404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit to the question, the Unicode data file BidiBrackets.txt shows all the matching bracket characters, where the opening character is `Ps`. As for quote characters `Pi`, there aren't too many of these, so I just found what looked like the most obvious closing character by hand:

```
« »
‘ ’
‛ ’
“ ”
‹ ›
⸂ ⸃
⸄ ⸅
⸉ ⸊
⸌ ⸍
⸜ ⸝
⸠ ⸡
```